# React access components from index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This might seem to be easy one, but i am totally confused.

I have developed react app, with components. Right now in my **index.html** i have working example:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div id="app-content">

        <!-- React will render in div#app-content, works fine! -->
                    <script src="build/main.bundle.js"></script>        </div>  </div>
```

project directory:

[image]

I want to **access component react component App from browser** java script,to implement this app in existing project like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="component">
        <script>
            // how can i call App component to render 
            // in div#components from here
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

the  file **build/main.bundle.js** was generated using [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/),
i have following files:
**webpack.config.js** :

> ```
> var webpack = require("webpack");
>
> module.exports = {
> /* This is the default setting for webpack */
> target: "web",
> /* Generate source-maps for browser side debugging */
> devtool: "source-map",
> /* Entry file to start building from. This is where you will want to start
>  * your project.  If you wanted to build multiple entry points you could 
>  * list them below.
>  */
> entry: {
>     main: "./src/main"
> },
> /* Defines where to output the final built files. The [name] definition
>  * is based off of the entry point's name. This example will generate
>  * a main.bundle.js in the public/build directory.
>  */
> output: {
>     path: "./public/build",
>     filename: "[name].bundle.js"
> },
> resolve: {
>     /* Defines where it can load modules from. Since we've installed our 
>      * JS dependencies through npm, it can look in the node_modules
>      * directory. If you use bower, you can add 'bower_components'
>      * to the list.
>      */
>     modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
>     /* List extensions to load in require() statements. The '' entry
>      * is needed to allow you to require src/main.jsx as require('src/main.jsx')
>      */
>     extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
> },
>
> /* Defines what modules to use */
> module: {
>     /* Loaders are how webpack compiles and builds the JSX extensions */
>     loaders: [
>         /* Any file with a .jsx extension will go through the jsx-loader */
>         { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: "jsx-loader?harmony" }
>
>         //add loader 
>         // { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: ""}
>     ]
> },
> //uncoment to use compression
>
> // plugins: [
> //     new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
> //         compress: {
> //             warnings: false
> //         }
> //     }),
>
> // ]
> };
> ```

**main.jsx**:

> ```
>     var React = require('react');
>     var App = require('./components/App');
>
>     if(typeof document !== "undefined")
>     {
>        React.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app-content"));
>     }
> ```

**App.jsx**:

> ```
> var React = require('react');
> var LineChart = require('./LineChart');
> var HelloWorld = require('./HelloWorld');
>
> var chartOptions = { responsive: true };
>
>
> var dataBar = {
>     labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
>     datasets: [
>         {
>             label: "My First dataset",
>             fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
>             strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
>             highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
>             highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
>             data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
>         },
>         {
>             label: "My Second dataset",
>             fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
>             strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
>             highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
>             highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
>             data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
>         }
>     ]
> };
> var dataLine = {
>     labels: ["Viens", "Divi", "Tris", "Cetri", "Pieci", "Sesi", "Septini"],
>     datasets: [
>         {
>             label: "My First dataset",
>             data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 88]
>         },
>         {
>             label: "My Second dataset",
>             data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90, 98]
>         }
>     ]
> };
>
> var dataLine2 = {
>     labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
>     datasets: [
>         {
>             label: "My First dataset",
>             data: [11, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40,70]
>         },
>         {
>             label: "My Second dataset",
>             data: [80, 50, 49, 10, 20, 35, 55, 44]
>         },
>         {
>             label: "My Third dataset",
>             data: [102, 50, 80, 65, 25,80, 90]
>         },
>         {
>             label: "My 4 dataset",
>             data: [150, 50, 50, 50, 50, 70, 89]
>         },
>         {
>             label: "My 5 dataset",
>             data: [80, 20, 50, 78, 65, 45, 100]
>         },
>         {
>             label: "My 6 dataset",
>             data: [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40]
>         },
>         {
>             label: "My 7 dataset",
>             data: [55,66,77,88,99,100,44]
>         },
>     ]
> };
>
> var data = {
>     startDate: "13/01/2015",
>     endDate: "30/04/2015",
>     title: 'LineChartDemo',
>     chartData: dataLine
> };
>
> var data2 = {
>     startDate: "13/01/2015",
>     endDate: "30/04/2015",
>     title: 'LineChartDemo',
>     chartData: dataLine2
> };
>
> var App = React.createClass({
>     render: function(){
>         return (
>             <div id="app">
>                 <HelloWorld name="Rolands Usāns" />
>                 <LineChart data={data} imageExport={['png, jpeg']}/>
>                 <LineChart data={data2} imageExport={['png, jpeg']}/>
>
>             </div>
>         );
>     }
> });
>
>
> module.exports = App;
> ```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Why would you want to execute script in the middle of the DOM?

Comment: @wiredpraire Right now i have project based on MVC principle ( I have framework Yii 1.1.15 ), so i want to implement React components in existing views partialy.

Comment: just use `React.render` and target a particular element. You don't need to use inline scripts to make this work.

Comment: when i call React.render from **index.html** `<div class="container">
    <div id="component">
        <script>
            // how can i call App component to render 
            // in div#components from here
        </script>
    </div>
</div>` i get `React is undefined`, I have included **main.bundle.js** generated by webpack

Comment: Are you sure the bundle includes React? Check the file. It would seem like either it does not, or you're trying to use React before it's been downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this way:

In **index.html** file i use **divs with inital state attributes**, see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>React WebPack Barebones Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app-custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/daterangepicker-bs3.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="build/main.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">React + CharJs</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello React + ChartJs!</h1>
        <p>For more details, basic setup, usage, implementations see Github project</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="https://github.com/rolandsusans/reactjs_chartjs" role="button">Get me to source &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="ReactApp" type="LineChart" ajaxUrl="urlAjax1" excel="link1"pdf="link2"  minDate="02/02/2014" maxDate=""> </div>
    <div class="ReactApp" type="BarChart" excel="link3" pdf="link4" ajax="urlAjax2"></div> 
    <div class="ReactApp" type="BarChart" excel="link3" pdf="link4" ajax="urlAjax2"></div> 
  </div>

</body>
```

The **problem was in loading order**, that React was loaded before, so I implement following in my **main.jsx**

```
    var React = require('react');
var App = require('./components/App');

function run() {
  // get all divs where Graphs should be rendered
  var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('ReactApp');

  for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
     //actually call app render the graph with  
     React.render(<App />, targets[i]);
  };
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
} else {
  window.attachEvent('onload', run);
}
```

As result everything works fine! App renders in multiple divs as I wanted before.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. I fixed it by excluding react from webpack. And instead, referenced it from script tag.